# LP Word Problem Construction

Tags: linear-programming

I am having difficulty constructing the constraints on a word problem as follows:

The Brite-lite Company receives an order for 78 floor lamps, 198 dresser lamps, and
214 table lamps from condoski Corp. Brite-Lit ships orders in two types of containers.
The first costs \$15 and can hold 2 floor lamps and 4 table lamps or 2 floor lamps and 2
table lamps and 4 dresser lamps. The second costs $25 and can hold 3 floor lamps and
8 table lamps or 8 table lamps and 12 dresser lamps. Minimize the cost of the
containers to hold the order.

The fact that the containers can hold 2 different quantities each is the difficulty I am having. Would it be correct to just give 4 different variables, 2 for each container? Giving:

Minimize

$15(x_1 + x_2) + 25(y_1 + y_2) = z$

Subject to

$2x_1 + 2x_2 + 3y_1 \ge 78$

$4x_2 + 12y_2 \ge 198$

$4x_1 + 2x_2 + 8y_1 + 8y_2 \ge 214$

$x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \ge 0$

Comment: $\LaTeX$ hint:  you can use \ge to get $\ge$, which looks nicer than $\gt =$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have the right approach.  Your three subject to equations should be inequalities using $\ge$, however.  You need enough room for all the products, but it seems it should be acceptable to leave empty space if you can reduce the cost.

Comment: Ah yes that would make more sense, thank you :)